# Invoking SAS 9.2 to edit a program from the command line (windows)

Tags: sas

I've been Googling for an hour and can't find what should be the easiest thing.

I want to invoke SAS from the command line to edit a SAS program.

If I do this:

```
C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)\sas.exe mysasprogram.sas
```

it simply executes mysasprogram.sas.

Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through my registry and some more Googling, I got to this solution, that seems to work.  However, I haven't played enough to know the differences between SAS.EXE and SASOACT.EXE.

```
SASOACT.EXE action=Open datatype=SASFile filename="mysasprogram.sas"
```

Comment: SASOACT is the SAS OLE automation server controller.  It may launch a new process or send the file to a current process.  I don't know that I recommend using it this way - although it is capable of doing what you ask, I haven't found it highly reliable in the past.  But if you don't have any problems with it with your installation, it may be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Create files:

E:\sasedit.bat

```
set _pgm=%1
start "start" "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.3\sas.exe" -autoexec "E:\autoexec.sas"
```

E:\autoexec.sas

```
%let _pgm=%sysget(_pgm);
dm "whost;include '&_pgm';";
```

- mysasprogram.sas with anycontent in a path that doesn't require quotes (in DOS).

Run command:

```
E:\sasedit.bat E:\pathtomyfile\mysasprogram.sas
```

The syntax of autoexec code:
DM is display manager, WHOST command is calling SAS Enhanced Editor.

To use this with path requiring quotes you'd have to provide path in quotes and add some quoting treatment to autoexec code.

Another way to run some initial commands is via INITSTMT SAS command line option, but there will we have a problem with lots of quoting.

Comment: Nice.  I will be using this myself.

Comment: Clever solution, although I have no idea why someone would want to to this.  Also, I'd suggest adding the `-rsasuser` option to the `start` command to prevent this script from "locking" the SASUSER automatic library.

Answer (score 1):

Take a read of "[Double-Clicking a SAS® File: What Happens Next?](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/115-2013.pdf)"  Sandy Gibbs, Michele Mosca, and Donna Bennett, SAS Institute Inc.

The raw gist (for File Explorer in Windows operating system) is that the command

```
"C:\PROGRA~1\SASHome\SASFOU~1\9.3\core\sasexe\SASOACT.EXE"
   action=Open datatype=SASFile filename="%1" progid=SAS.Application.903
```

needs to be associated with the `.sas` filetype.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting [vasja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19327692/1165522) to work -- the call to %sysget was unable to retrieve the variable.

I ended up using a single file (launchsas.cmd):

```
set fn=%1
set fn=%filename:"=%
set command="%%let filename='%fn%'; dm 'whost;include &filename.;';"
start "start" C:\path\to\sas.exe -initstmt %command%
```

Note that the creation of the "filename" variable is to avoid problems with embedded quotation marks.